# Is there a function .net to convert a Json Web Key (JWK) of private key to a ECPrivateKeyParam or a Pem in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, bouncycastle, ecdsa

I'm trying to convert JWK of a private key which is stored in the session storage of a web application I'm using to a pem. I'm trying to get that and pass it to a function into my .net project.

So far I've looked at bouncycastle library but without any help.

This is what the JWK looks like

`"{"crv":"P-256","d":"BGpXh15UrqUrh3pvuIfPcLyk9oOLtklCADy8Mf00w08","ext":true,"key_ops":["sign"],"kty":"EC","x":"FmcL-VfmMZ5PzMRC2FKYjO_3GMzV14VU9FrhleY2ePQ","y":"jmSV0RKhTI8VN3Xk98KJKSqOk03gtUeMpUFlSKOcsSY"}"`

I was wondering if there is a way to convert this into a Pem string or a ECPrivateKeyParam which is from bouncycastle library.

Comment: No, there isn't.